# Multiple tinyMCE editors on one page with different heights, same config

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I can use the code below to apply the tinyMCE editor to both of my textareas on my form.  However, I would like one to be 100 tall and the other 200 tall.  I could just duplicate the init code and specify the id of each textarea.  But is there a way I can eliminate the duplicate settings and call them once? And then just specify the element id and height for each textarea?

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        plugins: "paste",
        width: "650",
        height: "200",
        theme: "advanced",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,|,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        valid_elements: "+a[id|style|rel|rev|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|onfocus|onblur|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup],-strong/-b[style],-em/-i[style],-strike[style],-u[style],#p[id|style|dir|align],-ol[style],-ul[style],-li[style],br,-sub[style],-sup[style],-blockquote[dir|style],-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|height|align|summary|style|dir|id|bordercolor],-tr[id|dir|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bordercolor],tbody[id],thead[id],tfoot[id],-td[id|dir|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bordercolor],-th[id|dir|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style],-div[id|dir|align|style],-span[!style],address[align|style],-h3[id|dir|align],-h4[id|dir|align],-h5[id|dir|align],-h6[id|style|dir|align],hr[style],dd[id|title|style|dir],dl[id|title|style|dir],dt[id|title|style|dir]",
        invalidElements: "h1,h2,font,img",
        valid_styles: { '*': 'color,font-weight,font-style' },
        entity_encoding: "named",
        cleanup_on_startup: true,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
        paste_remove_styles: true,
        paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
        paste_strip_class_attributes: true,
        onchange_callback: function (ed) {
            ed.save();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: 'paste_strip_class_attributes' cannot be set to 'true'. Valid option values are "none", "all", and "mso".

Comment: Unrelated to your question: 'invalidElements' should be written as: 'invalid_elements'.

Comment: Please specify which TinyMCE version you're using.